# Returning a node struct gives an "expected expression" error

Tags: c

I have a node struct that references a term struct that stores a coefficient and exponent. in the below code I am trying to combine like terms. I am getting the error: **error: expected expression
*return const node;***

```
//combining coefficients of terms with common exponents
node_t * combine_like_terms(const node_t * node){
    node_t *tempTerm;
    node_t *temp2;
    tempTerm = node->next_node;
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    while(tempTerm != NULL)
    {
      temp2 = tempTerm->next_node;
      if(node->term->exponent == tempTerm->term->exponent)
      {
        node->term->coefficient = node->term->coefficient + tempTerm->term->coefficient;
        free(tempTerm);
      }
      tempTerm = temp2;
    }
    node = node->next_node;
  }
    
  return const node;
}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: `const` is causing the error. Just `return node;` But you do need a `const` in the function signature, i.e. `const node_t * combine...`

Comment: Also `node = node->next_node;` is dubious. You should not be able to change the const pointer. I might think that argument should not be const as it seems the function is supposed to change it.